# Transform dataframe values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where all of the columns have values between -1 and 1. I wish to transform these values to either 0 or 1, depending whether the original value is positive or negative.

Is there a method that'd apply such transformation or do I have to do it by hand by iteration?

```
2014-02-19  -0.005585   2.273724    1.622362    2.971364    1.980529
2014-02-20  0.005761    0.139337    0.129309    0.007561    0.086854
2014-02-21  -0.001857   -0.868622   -0.555042   -0.591182   -0.488545
2014-02-24  0.006428    0.120364    0.217812    0.117301    0.358756
2014-02-25  -0.001697   0.032631    0.220509    -0.154151   0.592626
```

Should be

```
2014-02-19  0   1   1   1   1
2014-02-20  1   1   1   1   1
2014-02-21  0   0   0   0   0
2014-02-24  1   1   1   1   1
2014-02-25  0   1   1   0   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the date column is the index:

```
(df > 0).astype('int')
Out: 
            1  2  3  4  5
2014-02-19  0  1  1  1  1
2014-02-20  1  1  1  1  1
2014-02-21  0  0  0  0  0
2014-02-24  1  1  1  1  1
2014-02-25  0  1  1  0  1
```

If it is not the index, you can set it with `df = df.set_index('Date')`  where Date is the name of the column.

Comment: This is the appropriate answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

For brevity...

```
(df > 0) * 1
```

For speed...
`numpy`-fied version of `@ayhan's answer`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    (df.values > 0).astype(int),
    df.index, df.columns
)
```

---

Both yield

```
            1  2  3  4  5
2014-02-19  0  1  1  1  1
2014-02-20  1  1  1  1  1
2014-02-21  0  0  0  0  0
2014-02-24  1  1  1  1  1
2014-02-25  0  1  1  0  1
```